# I'm trying to make my first postgres Api by following a document someone made, but I keep running into an error that I don't understand

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compiler-errors, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm practicing making a web Api/postgres Api by following a document someone made for a rudimentary postgres Api. I don't have a lot of practice, and I keep getting an error when I type `Add-Migration InitialCreate` into the package manager console. it looks like this:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The entry point exited without ever building an IHost.
> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CustomerContext]' while attempting to activate 'CustomerContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

For reference, this is the document:
[page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbEAc.jpg)
[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9D5L.jpg)

This is Customer.cs:

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public required int Id { get; set; }
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }
    public required string LastName { get; set; }
    public required int Phone { get; set; }
    public required string Email { get; set; }
    public required string Sku { get; set; }
}
```

This is DbContext.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext(DbContextOptions<CustomerContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

This is Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
```

This is appsettings.json:

```json
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection":
 "Host=localhost;Database=your_database_name;Username=your_username;Password=your_password"
    }
}
```

I keep getting the same error. The package manager console tells me that the build started, that the build succeeded, and then I get the error. I'm still relatively new to this, but I have experience with Java and Python. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: how does the rest of  your program.cs looks like ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic that's everything I've coded.

Comment: Add these two lines : var app = builder.Build(); and app.Run(); and then try to run add migration command.

Comment: @J.Memisevic that worked! However, I still don't actually have a controller for the api, and  I haven't been able to scaffold one. Also, after running the command and updating Program.cs, I tried using the command "Update-Database", and got the error "28P01: password authentication failed for user "your_username"".

Comment: Ok. Well that is a different question. Since you don't have any experience with c# some tutorial about webapi and entity framework would be nice to watch - so you would understand how everything works.

Comment: as said @J.Memisevic you could create new post for this question. and for a now to scaffold a controller, install `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` and `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`. Use `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller` with options to create `CustomerController`. For the error, make sure your `appsettings.json` has correct PostgreSQL credentials. check user permissions in PostgreSQL, and verify environment variables if used. Run `Update-Database` again after corrections.

Comment: @J.Memisevic do you have any idea how to solve the error p"assword authentication failed for user "your_username"" I'm trying to run the final step, inputting Update-Database into the package manager console.